# Can I use the link given by chrome.runtime.getURL in script.src?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying but even though it's proper link, the script fails. Why?

```js
script = document.createElement('script')
script.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("my_file_from_extension.js")
console.log(script.src) // proper usable link
document.body.appendChild(script) // GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED
```

Answer (score 1):

I pasted "my_file_from_extension.js" into manifest's `web_accessible_resources` and it solved the issue.

Comment: Javascript is hard. Its documentation is poor. I'm sad.